# SQL return the row ONLY with the later date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following rows in a table:

```
user_id school_id graduation_date 
------- --------- ---------------
1             123      2006-05-19 
1             123      2008-05-19
2             123      2006-05-19
2             123      2008-05-19
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_school us, [user] u
WHERE us.user_id = u.user_id
AND us.school_id = 123
```

I want to add in a clause at the end here to return only a SINGLE row; the row that has the LATEST graduation date -- so in this case, the second of the two rows. I want to be able to get one row PER student.  So, the latest graduation date per student.

**EDIT - Keep in mind this is an abridged version of a VERY LARGE query with many JOINS... doing a TOP and ORDER BY will not suffice.  I need like a GREATEST(date) function or something.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the constraints you gave about the TOP and ORDER BY, you can't do these in one swoop.

You can find the most recent graduation date, then go find the row with it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
         school_id,
         row_number() over (partition by user_id order by graduation_date desc) position
  FROM user_school
) us,
[user] u
WHERE us.user_id = u.user_id
  AND position = 1 /* limits to highest graduation date */
```

Comment: This seems closer to what I'm looking for.  Trying it now.

Comment: I want to be able to get one row PER student.  So, the latest graduation date per student.  How would I do that?

Comment: I assume the three columns you mentioned are the only columns on the user_school table?  There is no surrogate key?  I will update assuming there isn't.  That complicates things, but can still be done.

Comment: Tom's answer below is actually better than mine if you are willing to change what table you are selecting from.  If your "outer" query requires this table to be used, then mine will work.  But I definitely prefer Tom's.  It's simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is using `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (SELECT *,
             row_number() over (partition by us.user_id
                                order by graduation_date desc) as seqnum
      FROM user_school us join
           [user] u
           on us.user_id = u.user_id
      where us.school_id = 123
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'm not sure if I understand the question, but according what I got, this should do the trick

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_school us, [user] u
WHERE us.user_id = u.user_id
AND us.user_id = 1
ORDER BY u.graduation_date DESC
```

Comment: Ha, sorry you answered this before my edit.  See above please.

Comment: That does work in a simple case, but I'm not ONLY filtering by that row.

Comment: Can't you just `SELECT TOP 1 FROM` <your complex select statement>?

Comment: There are MANY other joins and columns omitted for the sake of brevity.  Is there a way to do this specifically against that date column?

Comment: Do you only want one resulting row or multiple rows?

Comment: I want one row PER student. Let me change my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_school us, [user] u 
WHERE us.user_id = u.user_id AND us.user_id = 1 
ORDER BY u.graduation_date DESC
```

Comment: There are MANY other joins and columns omitted for the sake of brevity.  Is there a way to do this specifically against that date column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the catch.  For some reason I thought I was using MySQL for this question.  I edited the answer for MS SQL.

Comment: @AdamLevitt Sorry, I'm not able to answer you on that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like:

```
SELECT
 field1,
 field2, 
 ...
   (SELECT MAX(graduation_date)
                       FROM user_school
                       WHERE user_id = us.user_id) as max_grad_date
FROM
 student_table_name
```